# Infinite scrolling works only twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, infinite-scroll

I've downloaded the infinite scrolling npm package but I encountered a problem.
The infinite scrolling is only working twice. I know there is a issue with code can anyone please review the code give suggestions?
sharing the code below:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Pokeitem from './Pokeitem'
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";


const PokeContainer = () => {
  const [PokeData, setPokeData] = useState({
    result: [],
    count: null,
    url:""
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])


  const getData = async () => {
   
    const url = `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/`
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json()
    // let newStr = parsedData.next.replace("?offset=20&limit=20","")
    setPokeData({ result: parsedData.results, count: parsedData.count,url:parsedData.next})
  }

 

  const fetchMoreData = async () => {

    console.log('PokeData.url')
    const url = PokeData.url
    // console.log(url);
    let data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json()
    console.log(parsedData.next);
    let Newdata = PokeData.result.concat(parsedData.results)
    setPokeData({result:Newdata,url:parsedData.next})
    // console.log(PokeData.result.concat(parsedData.results));

  }


  return (
    <div className='container my-4 '>
      <h2 className='text-center'><span className='text-danger'>PokéPedia</span> - The free Pokémon Encyclopedia</h2>
      <InfiniteScroll
        dataLength={PokeData.count}
        next={fetchMoreData}
        hasMore={hasMore={!PokeData.url==""?true:false}}
      >
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            {PokeData.result.map((pokemon) => {
              return <div className='col-md-4' key={pokemon.url}>
                <Pokeitem name={pokemon.name} data={pokemon.url} />
              </div>
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        </InfiniteScroll>
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default PokeContainer

::for better representation this is  what ParsedData is returning

```
{
"count": 1154,
"next": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=60&limit=20",
"previous": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=20",
"results": [
{
"name": "zubat",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/41/"
},
{
"name": "golbat",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/42/"
},
{
"name": "oddish",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/43/"
},
{
"name": "gloom",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/44/"
},
{
"name": "vileplume",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/45/"
},
{
"name": "paras",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/46/"
},
{
"name": "parasect",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/47/"
},
{
"name": "venonat",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/48/"
},
{
"name": "venomoth",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/49/"
},
{
"name": "diglett",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/50/"
},
{
"name": "dugtrio",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/51/"
},
{
"name": "meowth",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/52/"
},
{
"name": "persian",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/53/"
},
{
"name": "psyduck",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/54/"
},
{
"name": "golduck",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/55/"
},
{
"name": "mankey",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/56/"
},
{
"name": "primeape",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/57/"
},
{
"name": "growlithe",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/58/"
},
{
"name": "arcanine",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/59/"
},
{
"name": "poliwag",
"url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/60/"
}
]
}
```

Comment: hasMore needs to be true if next page exists

Comment: still not working,please help.

Comment: just tried your code on codesandbox and its working
Just change this 
``hasMore={hasMore={!PokeData.url==""?true:false}}``
to 
``hasMore={ !PokeData.url === "" ? true : false }``